# NGINX giving 404 error while fetching the css, js files with tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, nginx

I've deployed my application on tomcat and the directory for deployed app is `/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/myApp/`. In front of Tomcat I've assembled an NGINX reverse proxy server. Following is my nginx.conf.

```
server{
                listen 80;
                server_name 130.211.123.208;
                root /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/myApp/;
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ /myApp/$1;
                location / {
                        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
                }
        }
```

I wanted to remove the name of the application from URL so I've used rewrite feature of NGINX to remove the app name from URL. Now when I hit the above IP, my application's home page is displayed but all the .css, .js, .jpg & .png files aren't loaded. NGINX gives an error of 404 not found. All required .css and .js files are present under the directory still NGINX is not able to find it.

Following is the one of my .css & .js URL

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value="/resources/bower_components/material-design-lite/material.min.css"/>">

<script src="<c:url value="/resources/bower_components/material-design-lite/material.min.js"/>"></script>
```

This particular file is present under the same folder but still the NGINX couldn't find the file.

What do I've to do to resolve this part, also is URL rewriting is a good idea to target particular directory/app deployed under `/TOMCAT_PATH/webapps/??`

Comment: maybe you should try application.getContextPath() for your urls in the jsps..when proxying,/resources will try to find resources in the same level as request..

Comment: Didn't work..........

Comment: In this nginx conf, `root` and `rewrite` directives are redundant because all requests will be passed to `http://127.0.0.1:8080` in any case

Comment: @user1561188 Did you use the nginx only to remove the name of the application from the url - make example.com/MyApp -> example.com/ ?